# SQL Query works in Postgres pgAdmin but not in Prisma Raw ORM

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, prisma, pgadmin

As the header states, I have a query that runs properly on pgAdmin but when using Prisma ORM it fails.
I'm using typeScript and Next.js.
the query is parametrized.
Can anybody help?

this is the table:

```
model shift {
  id            String    @id @default(dbgenerated("uuid_generate_v4()")) @db.Uuid
  user_id       String    @db.VarChar(70)
  work_place_id String    @db.Uuid
  shift_start   DateTime  @db.Timestamp(6)
  shift_end     DateTime  @db.Timestamp(6)
  break_start   DateTime  @db.Timestamp(6)
  break_end     DateTime  @db.Timestamp(6)
  i_worked_on   String    @db.VarChar(150)
  notes         String    @db.VarChar(150)
  wage_per_hour Int
  tip_bonus     Int
  is_break_paid Boolean
  users         users     @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "shift_userId_fkey")
  workplace     workplace @relation(fields: [work_place_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "shift_workPlaceId_fkey")
}
```

this is the query that **WORKS** in pgAdmin:

```
SELECT SUM(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (shift_end - shift_start))) / 3600 AS "totalDuration"
FROM shift
WHERE shift_start::timestamp > '2023-06-30T21:00:00.000Z'::timestamp
AND work_place_id = 'cfbbf97d-8db0-49e9-830e-d3c6ab5dd473'::uuid
```

This is the parametrized query that runs by Prisma ORM that **WON'T WORK**:
`end, start` are strings that represents column names (i.e. 'shift_start').
`workPlaceId` is a string in uuid format.
`ealiest` is of Date type.

```
const decimalDuration: { totalDuration: number }[] = await this.client.$queryRawUnsafe(`
          SELECT SUM(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ($1 - $2))) / 3600 AS "totalDuration"
          FROM shift
          WHERE $2::timestamp > '$3'::timestamp
          AND work_place_id = $4::uuid
        `,
        end,
        start,
        earliest,
        workPlaceId
        )
```

This is the error Im getting:

```
Raw query failed. Code: `42883`. Message: `db error: ERROR: operator does not exist: text - text
HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`
```

But when trying to cast $1 and $2 like it suggests, i get this error:

```
Raw query failed. Code: `22007`. Message: `db error: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "$3"`
```

Comment: ``'$3'::timestamp``  - there ``'`` seems unnecessary

Comment: assuming that Im casting $1 and $2 to avoid the first error i've mentioned, foolowing @ValNik suggestion gets this error: `Raw query failed. Code: `22007`. Message: `db error: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "shift_start"`

Comment: Can you try this query?

const decimalDuration: { totalDuration: number }[] = await this.client.$queryRawUnsafe(`
    SELECT SUM(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ((($1)::timestamp) - (($2)::timestamp)))) / 3600 AS "totalDuration"
    FROM shift
    WHERE (($2)::timestamp) > ($3)::timestamp
    AND work_place_id = $4::uuid
`,
end,
start,
earliest.toISOString(),
workPlaceId
)